SQL - Find how many users logged into my site N times over the last year
I am looking to build an idea of how many unique visitors who have logged in to my site have had repeat visits over the last year
For example if I had 100k unique visitors YTD I would like to calculate how many times each user logged into the site for example build the below chart:
5k customers – 3 visits
40k – 2 visits
45k - 1 visit
This is what I currently have which seems to be doing the job mostly apart from some fringe results, i.e 1 user logged in 100k times, I feel like I'm missing a way to make it distinct
SELECT visit_count, COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM (
    SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*) AS visit_count
    FROM database
    WHERE auth_succeeded = 'true' AND (log_time BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-08-01')
    GROUP BY USER_ID
) AS visit_counts
GROUP BY visit_count
ORDER BY visit_count;


You want to count(distinct user_id) as user_count in the outer select in case multiple users collide for the same number of visits. You also want to make sure count(*) as visit_count is counting deduped logins

You can highlight users who have more than a certain number of visits.
Every user with more than 3 (for example) visits grouped separately. For example, users 1 and 7.
See example



user_id
auth_succeeded
log_time




1
t
2024-07-30 12:00:00


1
t
2024-07-30 12:01:00


1
t
2024-07-30 12:02:00


1
t
2024-07-30 12:03:00


2
t
2024-07-30 12:05:00


3
t
2024-07-30 12:05:00


3
t
2024-07-30 12:06:00


4
t
2024-07-30 12:05:00


4
t
2024-07-30 12:07:00


5
t
2024-07-30 12:15:00


6
t
2024-07-30 12:15:00


7
t
2024-07-30 12:05:00


7
t
2024-07-30 12:06:00


7
t
2024-07-30 12:07:00


7
t
2024-07-30 12:08:00



SELECT visit_count, COUNT(*) AS user_count
  ,case when active_user>0 then active_user else null end active_user
FROM (
    SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*) AS visit_count
      ,case when count(*)<3 then 0 else user_id end active_user
    FROM logs
    WHERE auth_succeeded = 'true' AND (log_time BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-08-01')
    GROUP BY USER_ID
) AS visit_counts
GROUP BY visit_count,active_user
ORDER BY visit_count;




visit_count
user_count
active_user




1
3
null


2
2
null


4
1
1


4
1
7



fiddle
